# syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE) - where is the issue though?

Tags: functions

This function below throws the following error: "syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE)"

This function and question is related to [this post.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328323/is-it-possible-to-insert-text-into-an-html-tag-using-functions-php)

```
function so328323_prefix_title( $title, $id = null ) {

    if ( get_post_type $id ) == 'tools-in-2019' {
        $title = "123 " . $title;
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'so328323_prefix_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
if ( get_post_type $id ) == 'tools-in-2019' {
```

Basically what your doing in this line makes no sense at all - you try to compare if conditions with some string... And you try to call a function, but you’re ignoring all PHP syntax.

It should be like this:

```
if ( get_post_type( $id ) == 'tools-in-2019' ) {
```